# Can't access my app from url in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am trying to access my application directly from **url** but was faced with this error message. I do not know why am getting that error below. My routes are properly set

```
NoMethodError in CategorsController#show
    undefined method `set_categor' for #<CategorsController:0x07087410> Did you mean? set_trace_func

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"viewnow"}
```

**routes settings**

```
resources :categors, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :show, :viewnow]
```

**controller files**

```
class CategorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_categor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :viewnow]

 def viewnow
   @categors=Categor.all
 end
end
```

**viewnow**

```
h1>This is view now page</h1>
<h1>Categors</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Cat name</th>
      <th>Car label</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @categors.each do |categor| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= categor.id %></td>
        <td><%= categor.cat_name %></td>
        <td><%= categor.car_label %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', categor %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
```

**here is how am accessing it at url**

```
localhost:3000/categors/viewnow
```

Comment: Please add your `set_categor` controller action to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your routes file

routes.rb

```
resources :categors, only: [:index, :new, :create, :destroy, :show]
match 'categors/viewnow' => 'categors#viewnow', via: :get
```

`resources` have default paths, and you can remove this default path from resources,
added this flag "only:", but if you need to add some new route, you can write new route with "`match`"!

or you can write the same in `routes.rb` a different way

```
resources :categors do
  collection do
    get 'viewnow'
  end
end
```